# JavaScript debugging, Murder Mystery game

Tags: arrays, debugging

In repl.it, the errors do not show, but in codeacademy, the errors range from wrong semicolon input and other errors. I've tried fixing the mistakes but I've had some trouble.

Here is the code:

```html
alert("Welcome to Mafia!");
var playeryou = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Choosing players");
players =["Bob", "John" , "Harry", "Tom", "Jerry", "Larry", "Joe", "Jesus", "Rivera", "Ben", "Noe", "Jose", "Adam", "Daniel", "Karen", "Megan", "Isaac", "Maggie", "Petra"];
console.log("A group of seven people who look like the mafia have been chosen to be voted by the townspeople to die. Each of these seven people could be a Mafia, Sheriff, or just a citizen.");
var player1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var player2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var player3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var player4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var player5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var player6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var player7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);

alert("You will be playing against " + players[player1] + ", " + players[player2] + ", " + players[player3] + ", " + players[player4] + ", " + players[player5] + ", " + players[player6] + ", and " + players[player7]);

Jobs = ["Mafia", "Sheriff", "Civilian", "Civilian",]; 

var jobplayer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayer3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayer4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayer5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayer6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayer7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
var jobplayeryou = Math.floor(Math.random() * Jobs.length);
console.log("You are a " + Jobs[jobplayeryou]);



var Mafia = 0;

if(jobplayer1 === 0){Mafia++}
if(jobplayer2 === 0){Mafia++}
if(jobplayer3 === 0){Mafia++}
if(jobplayer4 === 0){Mafia++}
if(jobplayer5 === 0){Mafia++}
if(jobplayer6 === 0){Mafia++}
if(jobplayer7 === 0){Mafia++}

console.log(Mafia);

suspicion1 = 0;
suspicion2 = 0;
suspicion3 = 0;
suspicion4 = 0;
suspicion5 = 0;
suspicion6 = 0;
suspicion7 = 0;
suspicionyou = 0;

gameover = false;
player1dead = false;
player2dead = false;
player3dead = false;
player4dead = false;
player5dead = false;
player6dead = false;

  console.log("There are " + Mafia + " Mafia in the town.");
  suspicion1 = 0;
  suspicion2 = 0;
  suspicion3 = 0;
  suspicion4 = 0;
  suspicion5 = 0;
  suspicion6 = 0;
  suspicion7 = 0;
  suspicionyou = 0;
  
  console.log("For refrance in voting and killing.");
    console.log("1 = " + players[player1]);
    console.log("2 = " + players[player2]);
    console.log("3 = " + players[player3]);
    console.log("4 = " + players[player4]);
    console.log("5 = " + players[player5]);
    console.log("6 = " + players[player6]);
    console.log("7 = " + players[player7]);
  
  
while(gameover === true || gamewin === true){
    var suspcion1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspcion2 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspcion3 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspcion4 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspcion5 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspcion6 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspcion7 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    var suspicionyou = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
    if(jobplayer1 === 0){suspicion1++}
    if(jobplayer2 === 0){suspicion2++}
    if(jobplayer3 === 0){suspicion3++}
    if(jobplayer4 === 0){suspicion4++}
    if(jobplayer5 === 0){suspicion5++}
    if(jobplayer6 === 0){suspicion6++}
    if(jobplayer7 === 0){suspicion7++}
    if(jobplayeryou === 0){suspicion++}
    if(jobplayer1 === 1){suspicion1 - 1}
    if(jobplayer2 === 1){suspicion2 - 1}
    if(jobplayer3 === 1){suspicion3 - 1}
    if(jobplayer4 === 1){suspicion4 - 1}
    if(jobplayer5 === 1){suspicion5 - 1}
    if(jobplayer6 === 1){suspicion6 - 1}
    if(jobplayer7 === 1){suspicion7 - 1}
    if(jobplayeryou === 1){suspicion - 1}
        var vote = prompt("Vote for the person that you want to kill.");
          if(vote === 1){suspicion1++}
          if(vote === 2){suspicion2++}
          if(vote === 3){suspicion3++}
          if(vote === 4){suspicion4++}
          if(vote === 5){suspicion5++}
          if(vote === 6){suspicion6++}
          if(vote === 7){suspicion7++}
          if(player1dead === true){suspicion1 = -1}
          if(player2dead === true){suspicion2 = -1}
          if(player3dead === true){suspicion3 = -1}
          if(player4dead === true){suspicion4 = -1}
          if(player5dead === true){suspicion5 = -1}
          if(player6dead === true){suspicion6 = -1}
          if(player7dead === true){suspicion7 = -1}
            if(suspicion1 === -1){console.log(players[player1] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion2 === -1){console.log(players[player2] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion3 === -1){console.log(players[player3] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion4 === -1){console.log(players[player4] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion5 === -1){console.log(players[player5] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion6 === -1){console.log(players[player6] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion7 === -1){console.log(players[player7] + " Is dead.");
            if(suspicion1 === 0){console.log(players[player1] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion2 === 0){console.log(players[player2] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion3 === 0){console.log(players[player3] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion4 === 0){console.log(players[player4] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion5 === 0){console.log(players[player5] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion6 === 0){console.log(players[player6] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion7 === 0){console.log(players[player7] + " Doesn't look like the killer at all.");
            if(suspicion1 === 1){console.log(players[player1] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion2 === 1){console.log(players[player2] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion3 === 1){console.log(players[player3] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion4 === 1){console.log(players[player4] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion5 === 1){console.log(players[player5] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion6 === 1){console.log(players[player6] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion7 === 1){console.log(players[player7] + " Doesn't look like the killer.");
            if(suspicion1 === 2){console.log(players[player1] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion2 === 2){console.log(players[player2] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion3 === 2){console.log(players[player3] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion4 === 2){console.log(players[player4] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion5 === 2){console.log(players[player5] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion6 === 2){console.log(players[player6] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion7 === 2){console.log(players[player7] + " Looks somewhat innocent");
            if(suspicion1 === 3){console.log(players[player1] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion2 === 3){console.log(players[player2] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion3 === 3){console.log(players[player3] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion4 === 3){console.log(players[player4] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion5 === 3){console.log(players[player5] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion6 === 3){console.log(players[player6] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion7 === 3){console.log(players[player7] + " Appears to be acting strange");
            if(suspicion1 === 4){console.log(players[player1] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion2 === 4){console.log(players[player2] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion3 === 4){console.log(players[player3] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion4 === 4){console.log(players[player4] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion5 === 4){console.log(players[player5] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion6 === 4){console.log(players[player6] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion7 === 4){console.log(players[player7] + " Is acting very suspicious.");
            if(suspicion1 === 5){console.log(players[player1] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicion2 === 5){console.log(players[player2] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicion3 === 5){console.log(players[player3] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicion4 === 5){console.log(players[player4] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicion5 === 5){console.log(players[player5] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicion6 === 5){console.log(players[player6] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicion7 === 5){console.log(players[player7] + " Looks like he's about to go on a killing spree.");
            if(suspicionyou === 0){console.log("Nobody voted for you");
            if(suspicionyou === 1){console.log("One person voted for you");
            if(suspicionyou === 2){console.log("A few people voted for you");
            if(suspicionyou === 3){console.log("Half of the people voted for you");
            if(suspicionyou === 4){console.log("Lots of people voted for you");
            if(suspicionyou === 5){console.log("You are probably going to die");
              suspicionaverage = suspicion1 + suspicion2 + suspicion3 + suspicion4 + suspicion5 + suspicion6 + suspicion7;
              suspicionaverage = suspicionaverage/7;
              suspicionaverage = Math.floor(suspicionaverage);
                if(suspicion1 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player1] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player1] + " was a " + jobplayer1[Jobs]) player1dead = true}
                if(suspicion2 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player2] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player2] + " was a " + jobplayer2[Jobs]) player2dead = true}
                if(suspicion3 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player3] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player3] + " was a " + jobplayer3[Jobs]) player3dead = true}
                if(suspicion4 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player4] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player4] + " was a " + jobplayer4[Jobs]) player4dead = true}
                if(suspicion5 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player5] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player5] + " was a " + jobplayer5[Jobs]) player5dead = true}
                if(suspicion6 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player6] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player6] + " was a " + jobplayer6[Jobs]) player6dead = true}
                if(suspicion7 > suspicionaverage){console.log(players[player7] + " Has been voted to die!" + players[player7] + " was a " + jobplayer7[Jobs]) player7dead = true}
                if(suspicionyou > suspicionaverage){console.log(playeryou + " Has been voted to die!" + playeryou + "was a " + jobplayeryou[Jobs]) gameover = true if(jobplayeryou === 0){console.log("You failed the Mafia! You died!") ;
                  Mafiakilled = 0;
                     if(jobplayer1 === 0 && player1dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     if(jobplayer2 === 0 && player2dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     if(jobplayer3 === 0 && player3dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     if(jobplayer4 === 0 && player4dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     if(jobplayer5 === 0 && player5dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     if(jobplayer6 === 0 && player6dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     if(jobplayer7 === 0 && player7dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
                     console.log("There are " + Mafiakilled + " left.");
                    console.log("Everybody goes to sleep");
                    
                    if(jobplayeryou === 0){var killed = prompt("Who will you kill?")}
                    
                    killedchosen = false;
                    killed = 0;
                    
                    while(killedchosen === false){
                    
                    if(killed = 1 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    
                    if(killed = 2 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    
                    if(killed = 3 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    
                    if(killed = 4 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    
                    if(killed = 5 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    
                    if(killed = 6 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    
                    if(killed = 7 && jobplayer != 0){console.log("You killed " + players[killed] + ".") killed chosen = true
                    else{console.log("You can't kill another mafia! Try someone else.")}
                    }
                    
                    playeridentity = 0;
                    
                  
                if(jobplayeryou === 1){var playeridentity = prompt("Who do you want to know the identity of?")}
                  if(playeridentity === 1){console.log(players[player1] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer1]);
                  if(playeridentity === 2){console.log(players[player2] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer2]);
                  if(playeridentity === 3){console.log(players[player3] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer3]);
                  if(playeridentity === 4){console.log(players[player4] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer4]
                  if(playeridentity === 5){console.log(players[player5] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer5]
                  if(playeridentity === 6){console.log(players[player6] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer6]
                  if(playeridentity === 7){console.log(players[player7] + " is a " + Jobs[jobplayer7]
                  
                if(maffia === 0 && jobplayeryou != 0){gamewin = true}
                if(maffia === 0 && jobplayeryou === 0){gameover = false}
                
                  
}

              if(maffia !== 0 && jobplayeryou !== 0){console.log("All Mafia have been killed, you win!")}
              if(maffia !== 0 && jobplayeryou !== 0){console.log("All Mafia have been killed, sadly, that means you too!")}
              
              console.log("Players:");
console.log(players[player1] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer1]);
console.log(players[player2] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer2]);
console.log(players[player3] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer3]);
console.log(players[player4] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer4]);
console.log(players[player5] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer5]);
console.log(players[player6] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer6]);
console.log(players[player7] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer7]);
console.log(players[player7] + " " + Jobs[jobplayer7]);
```

Can anyone send me the correct code so I could learn and use it?
If anyone needs some explanations on what something does, just ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try to fix your errors.
Something like [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) can help.

Make

```
players =[ ...
```

into

```
var players =[....
```

Same with `Jobs` and don't have the stray comma:

```
var Jobs = ["Mafia", "Sheriff", "Civilian", "Civilian"];
```

Put a `;` where needed:
e.g.

```
if(jobplayer1 === 0){Mafia++;}
```

And here

```
if(suspicion1 > suspicionaverage){
    console.log(players[player1] + " Has been voted to die!" + 
    players[player1] + " was a " + jobplayer1[Jobs]) player1dead = true
}
```

Did you mean

```
if(suspicion1 > suspicionaverage){
    console.log(players[player1] + " Has been voted to die!" + 
                players[player1] + " was a " + jobplayer1[Jobs]);
    player1dead = true;
}
```

What did you intend here:

```
if(jobplayer1 === 0 && player1dead = true){Mafiakilled++}
```

Perhaps

```
if(jobplayer1 === 0 && player1dead === true){Mafiakilled++;}
```

Sort the errors one at a time.

You might find it easier to have an `array` rather than variables named `suspicion1` ... `suspicion=7`, then you can loop instead of copy paste.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind. I'm working on my arrays, but I'm not confident enough to use them frequently!